# How to search a substring using FTS5 in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, search, substring, full-text-search, fts5

Suppose I have created a virtual table using FTS5 module in SQLite 3.35 like this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE TrialFTS USING fts5(search);
```

I have prepopulated the table with data.

[image]

Now to search any row that contains the phrase 'Black', I can search using:

```
select * from tri where TrialFTS MATCH 'black'
```

To search any row that contains any word starting with 'Black':

```
select * from tri where TrialFTS MATCH 'black*'
```

**But my problem is**- How to search any row using FTS5 that contains **'land'** as a **substring**, so that I can get rows with the words like **'England'** or **'Outlander'** etc?

I have tried:

```
select * from TrialFTS where TrialFTS MATCH 'land'
```

this does not work since 'land' needs to be a complete token/phrase in this case.

I have also tried:

```
select * from TrialFTS where TrialFTS MATCH '*land'
```

But this says: `unknown special query: land`
I cannot use simple pattern matching as 'like' keywords. I need to use FTS5 module without any tokenizer such as [The Experimental Trigram Tokenizer](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#_auxiliary_functions_:%7E:text=4.3.4.%20The%20Experimental%20Trigram%20Tokenizer)

**Please help me find a way to search substring in sqlite database using FTS5 module and no tokenizer.**

Answer (score 0):

Your can use LIKE to filter the result of the search as you would in a normal table.

```
select * from TrialFTS where search LIKE '%land%';
```

For LIKE to work, you need to use the name of the column you defined, instead of the Virtual Table Name, and you have to use % instead of *.

You can also mix MATCH and LIKE:

```
select * from TrialFTS where TrialFTS MATCH 'black' AND search LIKE '%land%';
```

Note that LIKE will not use the indexing capabilities of FTS5 and it will perform a full table scan of all your stored rows.

Comment: As you said- Note that LIKE will not use the indexing capabilities of FTS5 and it will perform a full table scan of all your stored rows.
I dont need LIKE and perform a full table scan of all your stored rows. Is there any other way to search a substring using FTS indexing?